# How to show reports on publisher/developer portal

Tags: azure-api-management

Is there any way to provide show all the reports which is visible under API Management> Analytic to admin on developer portal?

Individual user can see his report on developer portal but how admin can see for all the user apart of portal.azure

Answer (score 0):

Login to the Portal as an Administrator, Be sure that you are not logging in as a user.Then you can see all the analytics related to the APIM Like  **Top products**, **Top subscriptions**, **Top APIs** etc.
[img-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UbfT.png)

In the Top-right corner go to Administrator-->Profile-->Analytics Report

[img-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En8ay.png)

[img-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT9a6.png)

[img-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AmzV.png)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this report which you have shown in image is not providing user-wise report as shown in portal.azure